# Smooth self shadow on dense foliage

Tags: 3d, shaders, graphics, lighting, shadows

I don't know how to achieve or research smooth lighting on foliage, like in this screenshot of theHunter: Call of the Wild.

[image: press screenshot of “the hunter: call of the wild” with tall grass lit by a low sun]

The grass is translucent, but blocks light smoothly when it's tall and dense. It seems like an expensive effect, if you would implement it naively, so I wonder what the trick here might be. Unfortunately, I don't know other examples of this lighting and couldn't find resources for this game's graphics. I know that the games uses alpha planes for the plants.

Can you point me in the right direction to implement or research the used technique? Thanks!